# Best way to format a tabular display?

Tags: c++

I'm practicing my C++ skills and am writing an Employee pay information program that displays the employee's name, pay, address and whatnot. Here is what my layout looks like:

```
===== Employee Test Information ====================================================
| Name: Emily Rodgers                           Hire Date: 06/10/2017              |
| Address: 1055 Testing Ave., Madison WI                                           |
| Current Pay: $27.30                           Hourly?: Yes                       |
| Email: emily.rodgers@usbank.com                                                  |
====================================================================================
```

And it doesn't change if more/less text is entered:

```
===== Employee Test Information ====================================================
| Name: George Williams                         Hire Date: 12/10/2017              |
| Address: 21704 Fleming Rd., Madison WI                                           |
| Current Pay: $24.70                           Hourly?: Yes                       |
| Email: george.williams@usbank.com                                                |
====================================================================================
```

What is the best way to approach something like this?

Comment: You should post the code that you have tried. Someone could do it for you, but then you wouldn't really learn as much.

Comment: Also no one should want to do it for you

Comment: I'm not asking for code lol. I'm asking what would be the best way to create something like this format-wise. I've tried using tabs and the spacing is all over the place.

Comment: In C++, use [std::setw()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) stream manipulator to control the width of an output'ed value. [std::setfill()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill) will also be useful. (Personally, though, I'd use perl formats for this sort of thing instead of C++).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's several manipulators found in the *iomanip* header that you might find useful:

*setw* - this manipulator is used to output the value of an expression in a specific number of columns. Usage example:

```
    std::cout << setw(5) << expression;
```

This outputs "expression" to a column of 5 characters. So in your example, you have your info divided into two main columns of information. Figure out how many characters will fit into each of those two main columns. Then you would use the *setw* manipulator to ensure that your data fills the column. You know how long your labels are, because they're constant, so all you would have to do is use the *setw* manipulator to be the difference of the length of the label from the overall length of that main column. Do the same thing for the second column of information. Do one line of output with two *setw* calls. Example:

```
#include <iomanip>    
std::cout << setw(5) << expression1 << setw(10) << expression2 << std::endl;
std::cout << setw(5) << expression3 << setw(10) << expression3 << std::endl;
```

As long as the formatting is the same on each line, the output should appear in columns.

Other manipulators you might find helpful in your report:

*setfill(ch)* - This fills in the blank spaces with what the character *ch*.

*left* - Sets left sided justification.

*right* - Sets right sided justification.

More info can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/iomanip